# WebDriver - How to verify if an alert is present?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, alert

In selenium2 (Webdriver)How to verify if an alert is present? and continue doing something if its not present!!!

I am doing this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btn_may_or_maynot_showalert")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
try{
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("No alert");
}
driver.findElement(By.id("Cont_doing_something")).click();
```

This works fine But is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're doing things the way the library expects you to. However, one of the principles of the library is that you should always know what to expect of your automation code. That means you shouldn't run into an instance where the button "may or may not" cause an alert; you should already know whether pressing the button will cause an alert or not. If it does something other than what you expect, that's an exceptional condition, and an exception should be thrown.

Comment: What if you are automating your tests on a website, that when changes are made to the site you alert the users, the user click ok, and the next time the user logs in, if no changes are made, they are not alerted. Wouldn't you want a way to test that?

Comment: Sure, but since you're writing the test, you should know _a priori_ whether or not changes have been made since your test user's last login, and therefore, whether or not an alert is expected to be displayed. If you're not certain of this, or if your test runs in an environment where there may be changes that you as the tester might not know about in advance, then your entire testing strategy could be suspect.